# Clean way to make footer stick to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to get my footer stick to the bottom of the website, I haven't seen a good answer for making the footer stick to the bottom, when the page height is less than the viewport height and when the viewport height is less than the page height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a sticky footer using flexbox.
Whereas your `main` grows using `flex-grow:1` if the content is smaller than the height of the screen.

Whereas these are to important parts of the code snippet:

```css
html,body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

---

```css
header, footer {
  height: 50px;
}

header {
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

footer {
  background-color: red;
}

html,body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

p.s.
This works mainly because of the set `min-height` and the setting `flex-grow: 1` on the flex-child in the middle of the flex-container.

Assuming you have 3 elements in the flex-container with a set height.
The element with `flex-grow: 1` will fill the remaining space to reach the parents height. While the other 2 elements just have their height depending on their content.

So as soon your content reaches a size where the content elements `min-height` is reached, there is no space to fill anymore and it will behave normally like an element with `height: auto`

Comment: Thank's! it worked wonders! Can you elaborate on why this setup works?

Comment: I extended the answer. Unsure, if this satisfies your question. But if you have any specific question just ask.

Comment: Nope, thank you for explaining. I understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a sticky footer, you can use `position: fixed;`. For example;

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I want it to go to the bottom of the page when the page is smaller than the window height, and when it is not to just be added at the bottom of the content. I don't want it fixed.

Comment: In this case jcal's answer should do the job.